# Background thread progress notification in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

How do I modify an MVVM view model `Progress` property for work being done on a background thread?

I am creating an MVVM app that executes a task on a background thread, using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and `Parallel.ForEach()`. I am using [this article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/parallelizing-windows) as a guide. So far, my code looks like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(fileList, viewModel));
```

Where `fileList` is a list of files to be processed, and `viewModel` is the view model with the `Progress` property. The `DoWork()` method looks like this, so far:

```
private object DoWork(string[] fileList, ProgressDialogViewModel viewModel)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(fileList, imagePath => ProcessImage(imagePath));
}
```

The `ProcessImage()` method does the actual image processing. The view model's `Progress` property is bound to a progress bar in a dialog that is displayed just before the background process begins.

I'd like to update the view model `Progress` property after each iteration of the `Parallel.ForEach()` statement. All I need to do is increment the property value. How do I do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `Progress` just an int, float, or double?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the property is a simple property (and not a collection), you should be able to set it directly.  WPF will handle the marshaling back to the UI thread automatically.

However, in order to avoid a race condition, you'll need to handle the incrementing of your "done" counter explicitly.  This could be something like:

```
private object DoWork(string[] fileList, ProgressDialogViewModel viewModel)
{
    int done; // For proper synchronization
    Parallel.ForEach(fileList, 
       imagePath => 
       {
           ProcessImage(imagePath));
           Interlocked.Increment(ref done);
           viewModel.Progress = done;
       }
}
```

Comment: And once again, thanks Reed! I seem to be saying this a lot! Accepted and +1.