# Closing WPF window before Task completes

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I'm working on a project where I am updating bound properties (MVVM) from a background thread using a Task object:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // 1. Update bound control to indicate that data is being loaded

            // 2. Perform long running call

            // 3. Display the loaded data in the bound control
        });
```

The code above is the gist of what I am doing. From information I gathered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237317/background-thread-progress-notification-in-mvvm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994714/updating-bound-properties-from-a-background-thread) I understand updating the properties on my View Model from the task thread is not a problem - I am having no issues with this.

My question is - what happens when the window containing the bound controls are closed before the task finishes Step 2? I am not getting any errors and putting a breakpoint on Step 3 does not get hit when I close the window.

Comment: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with updating your ViewModel after the View has been disposed. The bindings will be broken by WPF and the view will no longer be connected to you ViewModel. The PropertyChanged events will just go unnoticed. That's the beauty of MVVM: you don't have to worry about what the view is doing when you work in the VM layer.